# Using a modal to delete a user

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a modal that when you click delete it will delete a record, but first I need to be able to have
that modal pop up.

I know that the reason is because of this line `$('#delete_{{ $user->id }}').click(function(){` but I'm not sure how to add the user id without having to add the `<script>...</script>` to the foreach loop

Or do I need to do that?

Here is my code

```
    <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Name
                </th>

                <th class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider text-right">
                    <a href="{{ route('users.create') }}" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 text-green-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">Add User</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <div class="ml-4">
                                <div class="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-900">
                                    {{ $user->name }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                                    {{ $user->email }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-right text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
                        <button id="delete_{{ $user->id }}" class="bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-300 text-red-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="modal-display-none">
        <div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
            <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
                <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity">
                    <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
                </div>

                <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen"></span>&#8203;

                <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full"
                     role="dialog"
                     aria-modal="true"
                     aria-labelledby="modal-headline">

                    <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                        <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                            <div class="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
                                <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-red-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.333.192 3 1.732 3z" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                                <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-headline">
                                    Delete User
                                </h3>

                                <div class="mt-2">
                                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                                        Are you sure you want to delete this user? <br>
                                        This action cannot be undone.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                        <span class="flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto">

                            <form action="{{ route('users.delete', ['user' => $user->id]) }}" method="POST">
                                @method('DELETE')
                                @csrf

                                <button type="button"
                                        class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-base leading-6 font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 focus:shadow-outline-red transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"
                                        id="confirm_delete"
                                >
                                Delete
                            </button>
                            </form>

                        </span>

                        <span class="mt-3 flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">
                            <button type="button" id="close" class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .modal-display-none{
            display: none;
        }

        .modal-display{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#delete_{{ $user->id }}').click(function(){
                console.log('delete button');
                $('.modal-display-none').removeClass('modal-display-none').addClass('modal-display');
            });

            $('#confirm_delete').click(function(){
                $('.modal-display').removeClass('modal-display').addClass('modal-display-none');
            });

            $('#close').click(function(){
                $('.modal-display').removeClass('modal-display').addClass('modal-display-none');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Which css library this is?

Answer (score 0):

replace your syntax (inside foreach)

```
<button id="delete_{{ $user->id }}" class="bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-300 text-red-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">Delete</button>
```

replace with this syntax bellow, it will show an alert to confirm the Delete action

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.delete', $user->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
    {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', [
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-300 text-red-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center',
    'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this item?')"
    ]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```